# Log4Net put log files in year and month folders

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I've tried several of the suggestions I've found here on StackOverflow and finally ended up with the following which seemed to get the job done:

```
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%appSetting{LogsFolder}\%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\MyLogs.log" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
        <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger (%property{culture}) %identity - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

However, after several months of logging I see that the configuration is incorrect, but I cannot see what is causing the problem.

I get a folder structure having *year* first and *month* second, but I still haven't got a folder for *12* yet (december). The newest folder I have is *11* and this one contains all logs for November from the 6th and to the 30th in addition to the logs for December.

The filenames are *MyLogs12112018.log* etc, where the pattern is day/month/year.

I would really like to add a *dot* (.) between *MyLogs* and the date but that is secondary.

However, why are the log files placed in incorrect folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%appSetting{LogsFolder}" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyy\\MM\\'MyLogs.'ddMMyyyy'.log'" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger (%property{culture}) %identity - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: It seems to be working.I'm not having the folder structure in the _datePattern_ locally, but I've updated my _staticLogFileName_ property to false which seems to do the trick. I want to check how this behaves when moving to february, so I'll accept your answer if the transition works.

Comment: The first three days have been placed in the 01 folder. My file type pattern is: %appSetting{LogsFolder}\%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\MyLogs..log, staticLogFileName is false and datePattern is "yyyy-MM-dd". There shouldn't be any difference in having the filename in file-value and datePattern as long as the datePattern produces unique groups should it?

Comment: Try using "\\" as opposed to "\" in the file-value. That worked for me.

Comment: It seems to handle month transition without any problems, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this second line :

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%appSetting{LogsFolder}\%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\%date{dd}\MyLogs.log" />''
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a folder for the days - I want all the files in one *month* folder.